# Subtract date which is retrieve from mysql database by 2 days using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I want to take date which should be before 2 days of expiry date. I am getting Expiry date from MYSQL database. Here is my code:

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * from assets");

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

echo "Start date:".$row["start_date"];

echo "Expiry date:".$row["expiry_date"];

$expdate=$row["expiry_date"];

$date=date('Y-m-d',strtotime('+2 days', $expdate));

echo "2 Days before Expiry date:".$date;

}
```

But I am getting output like this:

```
Start date:2012-05-01

Expiry date:2012-06-30

2 Days before Expiry date:1970-01-03
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 3):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

The 2nd argument of PHP's strtotime() function expects a Unix timestamp.  Try this instead:

```
$date=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($expdate.' +2 days'));
```

Answer (score 2):

The strtotime function takes two parameters

```
int strtotime ( string $time [, int $now = time() ] )
```

The second should be an integer, but it looks like you are passing it a string.
You need to convert it to an integer first. This should work:

```
$expdate_int = strtotime($expdate);
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+2 days', $expdate_int));
```

If appropriate, you could also look at doing the date maths in SQL

```
SELECT expdate, DATE_SUB(expdate, INTERVAL 2 DAY) AS two_days_before_exp
```

Answer (score 0):

You have asked for a day which is 2 days before expiry day .

```
  $date=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($expdate.'-2 days'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
strtotime('+2 days', $expdate)
```

Second argument must be a timestamp

http://php.net/strtotime

Answer (score 0):

Change your following line

```
$date=date('Y-m-d',strtotime('+2 days', $expdate));
```

to following

```
$date=date('Y-m-d',strtotime('-2 days', strtotime($expdate)));
```

strtotime second parameter expects timestamp (not a string date). "-2" to make it 2 days before.